# Who will be the owner of video uploaded through youtube direct?

Tags: php

I am working on a project where user can upload videos on my YouTube channel. I am using YouTube Direct Lite to create upload widget.

I wanted to know who will be the owner of those videos on YouTube?

Comment: Have you uploaded a video and checked?

Answer (score 0):

According to YouTube DirectLite documentation :

> The submission widget allows anyone visting your site to upload a new video to **their own YouTube account** from their hard drive, record a new video using their computer's webcam, or to submit a video that they've already uploaded for review.